# Native Base - The components placed in the Header are not vertically centered react-native

Tags: react-native, native-base

I tried customizing the theme of Native Base by using the Native base customizer [link](https://nativebase.io/customizer/). 
Once I applied this new customized theme the components in the Header are no longer vertically centered. You can see the extra space at the top. How can I fix this. The default theme works all right.

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Hi guys After looking into this issue in a greater detail I found the root cause of the misalignment. 
It was because of the theme which was downloaded via https://nativebase.io/customizer/ was taking 'ios' as the default platform and because of this the height of the header component was not proper in android and was according to IOS. 
On using the correct platform I was able to solve the issue in android.

Answer (score 0):

Check it out:

```
static navigationOptions = {
    headerTitleStyle: { justifyContent: 'center' }
}
```

Comment: You want me to add code for the native base header component? Well this is the code `<Header>     
          <Left>
             ....
          </Left>
          <Body>
            <Title>Message List</Title>
          </Body>
          <Right>
            ...
          </Right>
        </Header>`

Comment: For starters, reinstall NativBase to an older version if you have the latest version. Often the latest versions have errors

Comment: Additionally, use the version `"react-native": "0.55.4"`

Comment: I am using the same version "0.55.4"